# How can I fix my wna3100 Netgear wireless card always being stuck on "configuring device"?

Tags: 13.04, wireless, netgear

My wireless card (wna3100 Netgear) just won't connect to the internet. It's always stuck on "configuring device." I'm not much of a Unix person so any help would be greatly appreciated. I know there's a lot of posts about this subject already, but I can't follow reading the posts because there's too much Linux language I can't follow, so please treat me like an idiot and spell things out for me. Thanks.

Here's some info on my setup:

```
lsusb:
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0b57:8039 Beijing HanwangTechnology Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm   
          RTS thr:2347 B   Fragment thr:2346 B   
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

ndiswrapper -l

bcmwlhigh5 : driver installed
        device (0846:9020) present
```

Thanks guys for all the help.

Comment: you appear to have multiple accounts.  Please register one of these accounts.  Then click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request the merger of your other accounts.  Once done you'll be able to edit your question with further details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your instructions will be slightly different for the wna3100, but very similar. This is for the WDNA3100. You may need to change the wireless adapter name. Also, given that this is a card, you could load it in a windows machine, or just search for the driver file online.

- Install [Windows Wireless Drivers (`ndisgtk`) [image: Install ndisgtk]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ndisgtk) from the Ubuntu Software Center.
- Then, if you have a copy of Windows, plug your Wireless USB adapter in there and install. Find the driver called `bcmwlhigh5` (probably in `C:\program files\netgear\wnda3100v2\driver\winxp2000\`).
- Copy that driver over to Ubuntu, load up the "Windows Wireless Drivers" program, and load in the `bcmwlhigh5` driver.

Comment: From his `ndiswrapper` command, you can see that `bcmwlhigh5` is already installed.

Comment: I would still try to load it through the Windows Wireless drivers app and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Windows Wireless Drivers is a GUI for `ndiswrapper` =).